# Javascript copy object from function

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have problem when copy object from a function in JavaScript.

I have script :

## JavaScript

```
var _img;
fabric.Image.fromURL('phone.png', function(img){
    img.setWidth(320);
    img.setHeight(615);
    img.setLeft(0);
    img.setTop(0);
    canvas.insertAt(img, 0);
    img.set('evented', false);
    _img = Object.assign({}, img);
    console.log(_img);
});

console.log(_img);
```

the problem is, 2nd `console.log` result is `undefined` . I want to copy object from `img` to `_img` for reason. How to do that in a proper way ?.
Thank you.

**Edit :**
Thank you. I found solution from here : [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) . Now i can get return value from async call, here the code :

```
function addImage(callback){
  fabric.Image.fromURL('phone.png', function(img){
      callback (img);
  });
}


var _img;
addImage(function(result){
  _img = result; 
  console.log(_img); // result is ok
})
console.log(_img); // result still undefined
```

But, i still can pass the `result` to `_img` object. What should I do ?